# Can you enable two-step auth on a custom domain using gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, multi-factor-auth

I want to use a custom domain name for my e-mail, while still using gmail.  So for instance [me@myname.com].

However, I don't see an option to enable two-step authentication this way. I'm using the Google Apps Standard Edition.

Is it not possible to do that? Is it part of a paid service?

Comment: Are you referring to _Gmail for business_?

Comment: Nope. This was free. I'm not sure what the service is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible, paid but not for 2-step - just for custom domain.

**tl;dr;**

Usage of Google mail servers with custom domain requires *[Google Apps for Business](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/)*, formerly knowned just as *Google Apps*.

Quoting from [Google Apps Help Center](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120?hl=en)

> As of December 6, 2012, Google no longer offers new accounts for the free edition of Google Apps

To enable two step-authentication go to control panel of your domain:

- Security → Basic Settings → Two-step verification
- Click to checkbox *Allow users to turn on 2-step verification*

There's no additional fee for two step verification.